# Involuted vs Idempotent

Tags: linear-algebra, terminology

What is the difference between an "involuted" and an "idempotent" matrix?

I believe that they both have to do with inverse, perhaps "self inverse" matrices.

Or do they happen to refer to the same thing?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

A matrix $A$ is an involution if it is its own inverse, ie if

$$A^2 = I$$

A matrix $B$ is idempotent if it squares to itself, ie if

$$B^2 = B$$

The only invertible idempotent matrix is the identity matrix, which can be seen by multiplying both sides of the above equation by $B^{-1}$. An idempotent matrix is also known as a *projection*.

---

Involutions and idempotents are related to one another. If $A$ is idempotent then $I - 2A$ is an involution, and if $B$ is an involution, then $\tfrac{1}{2}(I\pm B)$ is idempotent.

Finally, if $B$ is idempotent then $I-B$ is also idempotent and if $A$ is an involution then $-A$ is also an involution.